# Alert / Warning window won't pop up at control location

Tags: c#, winforms, devexpress

I'm trying to get an automatically closing alert window to pop up under a specific control that's being used wrong by a user.

I'm currently using the [DevExpress `AlertControl`](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument5395) mechanism.  Its location needs to be set using the `BeforeFormShow` event, so I use the following manager class to set its location and show the alert with a specific message:

```
class AlertPopper
{
    private AlertControl _alert;
    private Form _form;
    private int _x, _y;

    /// Pass in an AlertControl to be managed by the AlertPopper.
    public AlertPopper(Form form, AlertControl alert)
    {
        _form = form;
        _alert = alert;
        _x = _y = 0;

        _alert.BeforeFormShow += SetAlertLocation;
    }

    private void SetAlertLocation(object sender, AlertFormEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(_x, _y);
    }

    public void DisplayAlert(int x, int y, string message)
    {
        _x = x;
        _y = y;

        var alertInfo = new AlertInfo("Warning", message);
        _alert.Show(_form, alertInfo);
    }

    public void DisplayAlert(Control control, string message)
    {
        DisplayAlert(control.Location.X, control.Location.Y, message);
    }
}
```

The intent is to catch an exception and display an alert under the relevant control like this:

```
// In form constructor, start the alert manager:
public MyForm()
{
    _alertPopper = new AlertPopper(this, this.AlertWarning);
}


// ... then in some event handler method, display the alert:
private void SomeControl_Click(Control sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // ... in some catch block for a recoverable exception
    _alertPopper.DisplayAlert(sender, "Bad thing happened.");
}
```

**But rather than the alert window appearing underneath the control, it appears far away (often on the wrong display of my two monitor set up, but not here):**

[image: Alert shows up relative to screen corner, not window corner]

It appears the coordinates are being treated relative to my screen corner, not my window corner.  How can I get the alert to display relative to the latter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use [`Control.PointToScreen`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.pointtoscreen(v=vs.110).aspx) method.
Here is example of your `DisplayAlert` method:

```
public void DisplayAlert(Control control, string message)
{
    var point = new Point(control.Width / 2, control.Height);
    var screenPoint = control.PointToScreen(point);

    DisplayAlert(screenPoint.X, screenPoint.Y, message);
}
```

Here is your event handler method:

```
private void SomeControl_Click(Control sender, EventArgs e)
{    
    _alertPopper.DisplayAlert(sender, "Bad thing happened.");
}
```

Comment: Well that worked perfectly.  Thanks for the clean solution!